# onclick event is not working when function is in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Before coming here I tried few links listed in stackoverflow, but none of them helped me to get this issue fixed Or may be I am doing something wrong.

I have a input button in my aspx and have **serverclick** event as well as **onclick**, both client and server methods are called correctly, I only facing problem when the 'onclick' function is in external file(it is in same directory).

I even referenced the js file in aspx.

NOTE :

> all other controls are working in external js except this.
>
> inline function works fine, but not when moved in external function.
>
> I even tried window.onload() but it triggers the function during pageload which is not what I need.

**aspx**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
```

**Input button.**

```
<input class="data" type="submit" name="cmdSubmit" value="Run Report" onclick="return FormValidate();" 
 onserverclick="RunReport" runat="server" id="Submit1" />
```

**external.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 function FormValidate() {
    alert("Validated");
  });
```

Comment: Check in console if there is some error

Comment: remove the `$(document).ready(function () {` around your function to make it global function.

Comment: Oh! I don't know, why I become so dumb!! @ vijay thanks for finding my mistake.

Comment: it happens many times...don't worry...Thanks @Manjuboyz...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `$(document).ready(function () {` present around your `function FormValidate()` to make it global function. Right now by placing it inside `ready` handler you are making it a local scoped function. So your **external.js** should be:

```
function FormValidate() {
    alert("Validated");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it as global function if written in external file

```
 function FormValidate() {
    alert("Validated");
  };
```

Removing `.ready(function...)` around it will make it global which will be called in html file.

Comment: This will actually throw an error because of the *);*.

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting scope of function keep it out of `.ready(function...)`
this will allow you function to be available globally